# How to parse a string to extract year range values and then store to database?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Actually I want to extract years from my string and then need to store into database.
So my string is

```
str = "1991-92,2013-14"
```

And I want the result as 1992 and 2014

How can I extract the year properly?

Comment: in which database sql?

Comment: @Sultan actually i want to store 1992 and 2014 as a string for some reason not in a date format

Comment: @ArupRakshit i think it is range of years .

Comment: That's makes sense.. :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit so my answer based on this thing.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Ruby regular expression`](http://rubular.com/) for extract year

```
=> str.split(',').map { |x| x[/(\d+{4})/].next }
#> ["1992", "2014"]
```

and increment with [`String#next`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-next) method.

**This work good only if all your range of years have step one year.**

Explain regexp:

- `(...)` Capture everything enclosed
- `\d` Any digit
- `4+` One or more of 4
- `f{4}`   Exactly 4 of f letter

Comment: I appreciate if you explain this Regexp which never I understood. 1+ for this

Comment: yes,but if the gap between the years is more than 1 year it will not work, so how do I that?

Answer (score 0):

It is bit of hack, but it does the job.

```
str.split(",").each do |year| 
    puts "#{year[0..1]}#{year[5..6]}"
end
```

Output:

```
1992
2014
```